# Android NFC: can we use intent filter with mime type? (android 2.3.3)

Tags: android, nfc

I'm trying to start an activity when "tapping" a nfc tag containing a specific mime type.
I made a tag with the mime type "text/plain", and added this in the manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
  <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

If I tap a nfc tag, nothing happen, even if the intent seems right, here is what I see in logs:

```
03-13 23:36:56.871: INFO/ActivityManager(114): Starting: Intent { act=android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED typ=text/plain flg=0x10000000 (has extras) } from pid 192
```

If I replace the "mime intent-filter" by this one:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/filter_nfc"/>
```

the activity is started when a tap the nfc tag.
I'm using a Nexus S on 2.3.3.

Any clues?

BR,
Patrick

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar problem and could solve it by adding a category element:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
  <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>

  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

</intent-filter>
```

-Oliver

Comment: That is true. Had same problem a while ago. I wonder why that is the case. Documentation does not say anything. Anybody asked google?